# Setting up an offline Tile Server for Terrain Data

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

I'm setting up an offline OpenStreetMap Server and need to provide terrain data as well. What exists to do this?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but couldn't you just add terrain polygons to whatever data your server returns and then add it as a layer to your client?

Comment: probably but I guess that involves returning the area of interest on the map then looking up the appropriate dted or SRTM files, then writing code to display the polys. I feel that this lib should already exist and am looking for out of box solution. - disclaimer: I am very new to mapping and just looking for a tool I can install and run offline.

Comment: Are you looking for server software that can provide tiled data as a service, or the data itself. If the former then you should probably ask the question on  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.  Certainly there are software that can provide tiled data through web services like WMS/WCS/WMTS.